# videoNotFound error on trying to upload thumbnail to youtube live stream

Tags: php, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to upload a thumbnail after the event is created and broadcast is binded to the stream. It throws a `videoNotFound` error even when the event resource exists. Is this because the video resource is not yet created in Youtube. This was working until two days ago.

Comment: Have you got some code?

Comment: I am using the code given in php samples, I am uploading the thumbnail after binding the broadcast to the stream

Comment: Yeah, um. We need the code that you are using. If the code is the same in the example then perhaps an issue with the youtube service? Maybe contact them?

Comment: I created a link to my code, please copy and open in editor. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WoSwC3i6a7DmO6nSX-gAq8YVW4utYVZK-ReL0tv0-e4/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks for the replies!

Comment: That's not your code that's just the API example code. Your going to have to debug that, perhaps with some echos and see what you get back. It doesn't seem like a problem with the API (otherwise more people would have this issue). TBO: best bet is do some digging show what you are doing and what the reply message is. Then show us also the issue tracker from youtube/api might be better https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new. Just looking at that tag and there are only 236 questions so not that muich expertise here.

Comment: Basically show how you are using the API.